# Java-Android okhttpclient post request timeout

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I do a post request an api running on my localhost but it throws TimeOut exception.
I set every timeout for 1 minutes but still getting error of timeout.
Here is my code for request :

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
           .readTimeout(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
           .writeTimeout(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
           .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
           .build();
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
           .add("Username", "***")
           .add("Password", "****")
           .build();

HttpUrl localUrl = HttpUrl.parse("http://192.168.1.40:44338/api/authorize/login");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
           .url(localUrl)
           .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
           .post(formBody)
           .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
        System.out.println("y" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("ccc :" + response.body().string());
    }
});
```

Comment: Your mobile device cannot find **192.168.1.40:44338**. From your mobile browser check are you able to access **192.168.1.40:44338** and see webserver default page opening?

Comment: No I'm not able to access it. But I asked this question here 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459255/java-okhttpclient-can-not-connect-to-localhost'  and they told me to change localhost as my ipv4 adress so i did it.

Comment: is your device connected to the same network your machine is in? If not pl connect to the same network wifi and try.